# How to install wgt from downloading on web

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Does anyone know how to install wgt on the devices on remove test lab? http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/. I tried it and it keeps telling me installation failed. Since i dont have access to a real device i cant install the wgt using the command line as some tutorials on the web. Is there something similar like unknown sources in android? Or how could i sideload wgt on one of the test lab device? Thanks

Comment: What does it show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these tutorials properly from

1. [denvycom](http://denvycom.com/blog/samsung-remote-testing-lab/)
2. Also check [this](http://mattpilz.com/samsung-remote-test-lab-test-android-apps-on-real-devices-for-free/)

[image]